# Modify instead of replace a config object when extending an ExtJs class

Tags: inheritance, extjs, extjs4.2

When extending an ExtJs class, the config objects are replaced by the new ones. But sometimes I would like to modify them only.

I give two examples and would like a general solution if possible.

Example 1. I have a panel with a toolbar and two buttons :

```
ExtJs.define('tbpanel', {
    extends: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    tbar: [
        {text: 'Add'}, 
        {text: 'Remove'}
   ], 
   ... 
})
```

When I extend it with the following code, the toolbar is overwritten :

```
ExtJs.define('final', {
    extends: 'tbpanel',
    tbar: [
        {text: 'Modify'}
   ]
})
```

How can I extend the panel, such that the final one has a toolbar with all three buttons?

Example 2: I have a store with a proxy config object that has several properties, like :

```
ExtJs.define('mystore', {
    proxy: {
        type: 'json', 
        writer: ... 
        reader: ...
    } 
})
```

When I extend it like this, obviously all proxy configurations get lost :

```
ExtJs.define('myspecialstore', {
    extends: 'mystore', 
    proxy: {
        extraParams: {special: true} 
    } 
})
```

How can I extend this store in a way that modifies the proxy instead of replacing it?

I prefer a general solution rather than two specific solutions.

Comment: You can't do this on a framework level, it would break everything. Create a method that compares the prototype of the parent class to your new config object and copy arrays or object properties from the parent to the new class, not the other way round. All objects have to be cloned, otherwise it affects the parent class as well. Then let Ext.define do the rest.

Comment: @BenjaminE. Where would you put this method ? In the `constructor` like @Nikolay or maybe in `initConfig` ?

Comment: What you want happens earlier in the process. You could try to override `Ext.Base.define` with an additional argument. Needs some experimentation and could get tricky. The easier and recommended way is to just use `initComponent` or `constructor`, but then you can't do exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use class constructor to get store `proxy` field and add your `extraParams` there.

```
constructor: function(config) {
    this.proxy['extraParams'] = {special: true};
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not general enough. I can't accept it as answer. Either you elaborate, or I will give a complete answer myself, once I finished my investigations.